# Delayed container startup

Tags: docker-compose

I have a Docker compose file consisting out of the app: digitalocean.com/php; a webserver: nginx:alpine and a db: mysql:5.7.22 container. My problem is, when I run "docker-compose up –d" I cannot access the webserver until I do a "docker restart webserver".

I think I have to add a delayed start for the webserver, which I tried with the wait-for-it script:

```
  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./wait-for-it.sh:/wait-for-it.sh
    depends_on:
      - app
      - db
    entrypoint: ./wait-for-it.sh db:3306
    networks:
      - app-network
```

However, the problem still exists. Is the entrypoint call wrong or how can I achieve a delayed start?

Thanks
Stephan

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure how I solved it but it seems to be working. In my webserver I had the extra condition:

```
depends_on:
      - app
```

And in the app I added the following healthcheck:

```
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
            timeout: 20s
            retries: 10
```

I am not exactly sure what it does, but now at least I don’t have to restart the web server